# Trim() Method not working inside double quotes

Tags: powershell

If I have a string like so:

```
$String = "Hello      world"
```

and attempt to prefix another string into it by:

```
$String | % {"Page 1   = ($_.trim())"}
```

I get back:

```
Page 1   = (Hello      world.trim())
```

I have tried a few other variations, the only one that worked is:

```
$String | % {($_.trim())}
```

Which is not ideal, as I need to prefix a string to multiple lines of text files.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you give an example of what the desired outcome should look like?

Comment: @HiTech Pardon me, I was expecting '"Page 1 = Helloworld'.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I awesome! that does it. You should have posted this as an answer :)

Comment: In addition to the subexpression mentione by the user above, you can use string concatenating, or string formatting. `"Page 1 = " + $_.Trim()` and `"Page 1 = {0}" -f $_.Trim()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to invoke an expression embedded in a string, that's exactly what the [Subexpression Operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#subexpression-operator--) is for. As aside, your [`.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0) wouldn't do anything on that example string because it can only trim **exceeding leading or trailing whitespace**.

If your string looked like this then `Trim()` would be perfect:

```bash
$String = "   Hello World   "
$String | ForEach-Object { "Page 1   = $($_.Trim()')" }
```

However, it seems you actually want to remove the exceeding white space from the middle of the string, in that case you can use [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator):

```bash
$String = "Hello     World"
$String | ForEach-Object { "Page 1   = $($_ -replace '\s')" }
# if you want to leave a white space in the middle
$String | ForEach-Object { "Page 1   = $($_ -replace '\s+', ' ')" }
```

Comment: Maybe `$($_ -replace '\s+', [char]32)` to keep right one space?

Comment: @JosefZ I'm not sure what OPs expected output is so will wait on that, but thanks for the feedback